# Horizontally center a image slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a image slider in flutter where I want to vertically center the carousel. I'm using [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider). And this here is my code:

```
  Widget _buildItems(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        appBar(context),
        Center(
          child: CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              enableInfiniteScroll: false,
              autoPlay: false,
            ),
            items: widget.recipeStepsList!
                .map(
                  (e) => ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    child: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            e.name!,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Image.network(
                          e.stepThumbnailLink!,
                          width: 1000,
                          height: 200,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

As you can see, I've already wrapped everything inside a `Center` but this is the outcome of my code:

[image]

The only reason the back button is in place because it has a padding of 10. But since I'm building this application for all types of screens I need to keep the image slider exactly in the center.

Comment: You mean vertically centered? If so, try specifying `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` under `Column`

Comment: @AbdurRafaySaleem yes vertically. Thanks for noticing

Comment: If that doesn't work. Try wrapping `Column` with a `Center` and remove `Center` around the carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carousel is not coming in the center, since your `Center` widget is not actually taking up the full space and this is because it is inside a `Column`.

For widget like `Row` and `Column`, you can use `Expanded` widget to make any child take up the remaining space.

So, for your case, just wrap your `Center` inside an `Expanded`.

Here is the linkk to [full working code](https://pastebin.com/kwikNQVu).

Result,

Ignore the overflow warning, since that is happening because the `carousel` package is squishing view while scrolling.

[image]

Comment: hi, I tried going with expanded but I get this error `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
`

Comment: I wrapped the center widget with an expanded

Comment: I had to use a sized box with the `height:height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.75,`

I would've divided it by 2 to get the half of screen height but the appBar has a padding of 10. So, 1.75 to mitigate that. Is this a good solution or should I just go with the expanded?

Comment: The `MediaQuery` way is a hack since you dont know the dimensions of all screens. `1.75` on one screen would be the same as `1.75` on another screen.

Comment: Is my solution not working ? Could you paste your code in a https://pastebin.com/ and give me then link, i'll checkk it.

Comment: here's the link where I tried to wrap the Center in an expanded.
I have to write the names of the images under the images. That's why I used the column.

https://pastebin.com/eHDPkQah

Comment: `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#dcde5 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
`

This is the error

Comment: You don't need a single child scroll view. Have updated my answer wtih link to full code. Check it out. https://pastebin.com/kwikNQVu

Comment: yeah that worked, although the pictures on the left and right were having a renderoverflow problem which I fixed. Thanks a lot man

Comment: Wonderful, Glad to have helped :) What way did you choose to fix the overflow ? I am learning flutter as well.

Comment: that's great. I wrapped the `ClipRRect` with an `Expanded` and that did the trick. I removed the height constrain from `Image` but kept the width.